# does DFS and BFS in O(n+m) change?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

We know there is an `O(n+m)‌` ‌solution (DFS ‌or BFS) for checking if there is a path from `s` to `t` in a Undirected Graph `G` with `n` vertexes and `m` edges... that would be implemented via an adjacency List.

If I implement my program with *Adjacency Matrix*, will the runtime be affected? Is this a good or bad choice?

Edit: I‌ Need to calculate the time complexity, in this way, any idea?

Comment: So, you want to know whether an Adjacency Matrix is faster? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes. Depends. This question has been asked many times.

Comment: @FrankV, you are right, I edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input to your code will be `n` and `m` ( number of nodes and the number of edges ) followed by `m` lines of the type `a b` signifying there is an edge between vertex `a` and vertex `b`. Now you take an adjacency matrix `M[][]` such that `M[i][j]=1` if there is an edge between `i` and `j` otherwise `M[i][j]=0` ( as graph is undirected the matrix will be symmetric, thus you can only store the upper/lower half matrix reducing memory by half ). Now you will have to take the matrix and initialize it to 0 ( all the cells ) and while scanning the edges mark `M[a][b]=M[b][a]=1`. Now the initializing part is `O(n^2)`. Scanning and marking the edges is `O(m)`. Now lets look at the BFS/DFS routine. When you are at a node you try to see all its unvisited vertices. Now say we want to know the neighbors of vertex `a`, you will have to do `for(int i=0;i<n;i++) if (M[a][i]==1)` ( assuming 0 based indexing ). Now this has to be done for each vertex and thus the complexity of routine becomes `O(n^2)` even if `m < (n*(n-1))/2` ( assuming simple graph with no multiple edges and loops `m` can at maximum be `(n*(n-1))/2` ). **Thus overall your complexity becomes `O(n^2)`**. Then whats the use of adjacency matrix ? well the DFS/BFS might be just a part of a big algorithm, your algorithm might also require one tell if there is an edge between node `a` and `b` at which adjacency matrix takes `O(1)` time. Thus whether to choose adjacency list or adjacency matrix really depends on your algorithm ( such as maximum memory you can take, time complexity for things like DFS/BFS routine or answering queries whether two vertices are connected etc. ) .
Hope I answered your query.

Comment: so, at last, what is the last Time Complexity for it?

Comment: O(n^2) is the time complexity I have mentioned it in answer